# Linux shell script to check if another user has unread mail

Tags: linux, email

I'm looking to create a shell script that will accept userids as an argument to check if that user has unread mail in `/var/spool/mail`.

How would I even go about checking a user's mail status? Is `/var/spool/mail` only unread mail? If so, then I'm assuming I would just check for users with files of size greater than 0.

Comment: will this script be running as `root`, and does it need to be portable?

Comment: No it will not, and no it doesn't need to be portable.

Comment: you can get only the file size (unless something set a looser umask than my MTA does) but that will not tell you whether the mail has been read or not

Answer (score 1):

One method that is used to find unread mail is to check the timestamps on the mail spool file. If the file was written to after it was accessed (read), i.e. its `mtime` is greater than `atime`, then there is unread mail:

```
for f in /var/spool/mail/* ; do 
     [ $(stat -c '%Y -gt %X' "$f") ] && echo "$f has unread mail"
done
```

That of course considers everything in the mailbox as "read" after it's opened, regardless of if anyone looked at the individual messages.

In many cases, read messages are also moved away from the spool directory (to `~/mbox`), so you could do with just checking the file size.

Comment: I forgot to mention I don't have root access, will this still work? Also how does this script take in the userid as an argument? I need to check specific users.

Comment: To my understand the /var/spool/mail/ directory is a temporary directory that only holds unread mail. Once it is opened it is either deleted or moved to a different directory thats dedicated to the user. So I should be able to see if the user has unread mail in there just based off of the directory size. I'm just not sure if all of this adds up lol

Comment: @linuxnewbie, you only need `x` access to the directory to `stat` a file, and you have that anyway, since otherwise you couldn't reach your _own_ mail spool file. Of course, as written, it doesn't take an argument, but that's not a very hard exercise (start here: [Tests and Conditionals])http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals) and the [`stat(1)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html)). And sure, checking the size might be enough too. Depends on how the user works with their mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `mailx` (formerly `mail`) command with options `-e` and `u`:

> -e     Just check if mail is present in the system mailbox.  If yes, return an exit status of zero, else, a non-zero value.
>
> -u user
>                 Reads the mailbox of the given user name.

To allow non-root user to check the other user's email you have to create a `sudo` rule in the `/etc/sudoers` file that will allow that user to run `mailx` as root, e.g.:

```
fred localhost=/bin/mailx -e -u *
```

check `man sudoers` for the complete format.

Then you just test the exit status of

```
sudo mailx -e -u tom
```

executed by fred

Comment: This looks like a great method, but I forgot to mention that I don't have root access.

Comment: @linuxnewbie what keeps you from asking administrator to set the things for you if your intents are legitimate?

Comment: because this is a script/awk assignment and i'm only allowed to work with the permissions I currently have.